# Долгая установка пакетов NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, консоль, npm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при установке пакетов, начинает переустанавливать-обновлять все остальные пакеты? Это занимает очень много времени. Устанавливаю обычно npm i bootstrap

Comment: Покажите package.json

Comment: загрузил скриншот